# find { or } inside an element and wrap them with span

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<div id = "board>
    <div>{abc</div>
    <div>def</div>
    <div>ghi}</div>
</div>
```

I've already done this by span-wrapping all of the char first before comparing if it is { or }. But that is too slow, i need to reverse the procedure, is it possible to get the char position relative to the parent div?

Intended Output is

```
<div id = "board>
    <div><span>{</span>abc</div>
    <div>def</div>
    <div>ghi<span>}</span></div>
</div>
```

how about using **contains()** and **replace()**?

Comment: you mean position in pixels??

Comment: Can you further explain what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: no not in pixel, something like offset, for example the position of 'b' i am expecting is 2 (based 0)

Comment: this will be used for brace matching on my code editor. i need span so that i can highlight them

Comment: Why not just replace them? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: replacing noted, thanks ive updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use Regular Expressions:

```
var x = '<div id = "board>' + 
    '<div>{abc</div>' +
    '<div>def</div>' +
    '<div>ghi}</div>' +
    '</div>'; // or... get element by id 'board'

var rgx1 = /{/;
var rgx2 = /}/;

var y = x.replace(rgx1, "<span>{</span>");
y = y.replace(rgx2, "<span>}</span>");
```

if you think you have more than 1 occurrence of { or }, you can add "g" to the regex's:

```
var rgx1 = /{/g;
var rgx2 = /}/g;
```

Comment: do you have a demo of this because mine is not appending to the $('board')

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the markup:

```
<div id="board">
    <div>{abc</div>
    <div>def</div>
    <div>ghi}<div>
</div>
```

And your intended output is:

```
<div id="board">
    <span>abcdefghi</span>
</div>
```

You can do this using jQuery/javascript like this:

```
var textNodes = $("#board").find("div");
var text = "";

for(var i=0;i<textNodes.length;i++) {
    text = text + textNodes[i].text();
    $("#board").remove(textNodes[i]);
}

var spans = text.split("}");
var textToAppend = "";
for(i=0;i<spans.length - 1 ;i++)
    textToAppend = textToAppend + "<span>"+spans[i].split("{")[1]+"</span>";

$("#board").append(textToAppend);
```

Is this the solution you are looking for?

Edit 1:

If you need just the position of lets say b as 2, and d as 4?

Here is the code.

```
var textNodes = $("#board").find("div");
var text = "";

for(var i=0;i<textNodes.length;i++) {
    text = text + textNodes[i].text();        
}

var codeBlocks = text.split("}");
var firstBlock = codeBlocks[0];

var getCharPosInBlock = function (character) {
     if(character === "}") return firstBlock.length;
     return firstBlock.indexOf(character);
}
```

Comment: big help, post it again as the answer so i can mark it (for the benefit of the others)

Answer (score 0):

To get the required result using javascript looping:

```
var textNodes = $("#board").find("div");

for(var i=0;i<textNodes.length;i++) {
    var value = textNodes[i].text()
    if(value.indexOf("{") > 0) 
         textNodes[i].text(value.replace("{", "<span>{</span>"));
    if(value.indexOf("}") > 0) 
         textNodes[i].text(value.replace("{", "<span>}</span>"));
}
```

Comment: In case the dom is created in javascript and appended, the string regex match is the fastest option. If the dom already exists and we are modifying the same dom to do the highlighting, we would have to remove the dom, make changes and re-add it. This will trigger repainting and its slower. Here is a fiddle to show this: http://jsperf.com/dom-mod-test